# How to override a single item on a model form django

Tags: python, html, django

How does one correctly override the styling of a single item in Django's model form {{form}} call. I cant seem to just overide the defualt behaviour and add my necessary style.

Specifically, I would like to add a simple slider that passes through some text to the view.

I have added an extra field to my form as follows:

```
class CreateTestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    difficulty = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Test
```

And the following in my html directly:

```
<form method="POST" action=""> {% csrf_token %}
{{ form|crispy }}

<strong>Difficulty</strong>
<input id="difficulty" type="text" value="" class="slider form-control" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="10"
                         data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,10]" data-slider-orientation="horizontal"
                         data-slider-selection="before" data-slider-tooltip="show" data-slider-id="blue">
</br>
<input type='submit' value='Create' class='btn'>
</form>
```

However, when I render the view, I get two difficulties inputs (one slider and one box). I understand that Django is creating the text box for me, but I assumed, giving my slider the same id would simply override it?

From my belief, I would also have to have the slider defined in the forms.py class for this form, else it is not accessible in cleaned_data in the view. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would assume that. But why not define the relevant attributes in the form in the first place, so that they get output automatically?

```
difficulty = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "slider form-control", "data-slider-min": "0"...}))
```

Or even better, use the Crispy API to let you declare those attributes (I don't use Crispy myself, but I know it gives you a lot of extra control.)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default widget, adding your class for styling like so:

```
from django import forms
class CreateTestform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ['difficulty'] # you don't need to define difficulty again,
        # just get it from your model like in this example.
        widget = {
            'difficulty': forms.CharField(attrs={
                'class': 'name-of-your-class',
                'other-attribute': 'other-value',
            }),
        }
```

You can check for more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields).

If you have too much styling to apply to your form, I suggest to [render it manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) and I know you use cripsy to avoid that, but it's a easier way, without limits, django is supposed to be used for backend, not frontend.

You can even render like this (supposing you have to render difficulty):

```
<input class="whatever-your-class-is" name="{{ form.difficulty.html_name }}" id="{{ form.difficulty.id_for_label }}">
```

If you look carefully, you found information about `.html_name` and `.id_for_label`, even `.value` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields).